# Export Custom WooCommerce Checkout Field to ShipStation Custom Field 2

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to export a custom field from my checkout into custom field 2 in ShipStation but the data isn't getting pulled into the custom field 2. Am I maybe using the wrong meta in my code?

I've copied the snipped from ship stations site that I should add to my functions.php

```
// Add this code to your theme functions.php file or a custom plugin
add_filter( 'woocommerce_shipstation_export_custom_field_2', 'shipstation_custom_field_2' );

function shipstation_custom_field_2() {
    return '_meta_key'; // Replace this with the key of your custom field
}

// This is for custom field 3
add_filter( 'woocommerce_shipstation_export_custom_field_3', 'shipstation_custom_field_3' );

function shipstation_custom_field_3() {
    return '_meta_key_2'; // Replace this with the key of your custom field
}
```

For the site I'm working on, I have a custom checkout field on my checkout for out of stock options. I've replaced the '_meta_key_2' with the meta for the customers out of stock option 'outofstockoption'

```
function my_custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta( $order_id ) {
    if ( ! empty( $_POST['outofstockoption'] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $order_id, 'Out of Stock Option', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['outofstockoption'] ) );
    }
}

// Add this code to your theme functions.php file or a custom plugin
add_filter( 'woocommerce_shipstation_export_custom_field_2', 'shipstation_custom_field_2' );

function shipstation_custom_field_2() {
    return 'outofstockoption'; // Replace this with the key of your custom field
}
```

I'm hoping someone can guide me in the right direction on how to get ShipStation to pull the 'outofstockoption' and place this into the ShipStation custom field. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In your line -

```
update_post_meta( $order_id, 'Out of Stock Option', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['outofstockoption'] ) );
```

you are assigning the _meta_key as 'Out of Stock Option'.  To use this as the meta key and send it to ShipStation, update your function to -

```
function shipstation_custom_field_2() {
    return 'Out of Stock Option'; 
}
```